# binding parameters is causing a warning

Tags: php, mysqli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot use call_user_func_array on mysqli_stmt object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003890/cannot-use-call-user-func-array-on-mysqli-stmt-object)

I have a piece of mysqli code which is outputting a warning in this line of code:

```
if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($questionquery)) {
  die("Error preparing statement: $mysqli->error"); 
}
```

The warning is:

```
Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in ... line 80
```

Below is main code:

```
// Make the referenced array
$referencedArray = make_values_referenced(array_merge(
  array(str_repeat("ss", $numTerms)), // types
  $termArray,                         // where
  $termArray                          // order by
));

// ...or die() is evil in production but I shall assume we are debuggin so I won't complain
if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($questionquery)) {
  die("Error preparing statement: $mysqli->error"); 
}

// Bind parameters
if (!$stmt->bind_param($referencedArray)) {
  die("Error binding parameters: $stmt->error"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the method directly:

```
$stmt->bind_param($referencedArray);
```

EDIT: Actually I'm mistaken.  You need `call_user_func_array` for variable number of parameters.  See this answer for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5108167/163024

Comment: Hi, I updated question to include your line of code but I now get another warning. Can you please look at my updated question, it contains more code and it contains the line of code you gave me and the new warning it has given me

Comment: should it be `$stmt->bind_param(array($referencedArray));?
`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5108167/163024