# How to call mysqli_stmt with call_user_func_array?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to pass a variable number of arguments to a method of a class. Here is the function of the class that I am trying to invoke:

```
class DbHelper{
....
    public function Execute($query, $params){
        $this->open();
        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query) or die($this->mysqli->error);
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);  // 1
        return $stmt->execute() ? $stmt->num_rows : 'ERROR';
    }
....
}
```

Here is the code I am using to invoke the function:

```
....
$conn = new DbHelper();
$params = array('ss', $ID, $i);
$conn->Execute('INSERT INTO some_table (ID, `Index`) VALUES (?,?)', $params);
....
```

This gives an error:

> Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in ..mypath..\dbhelper.php on line

In my another post (click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003890/cannot-use-call-user-func-array-on-mysqli-stmt-object)) on same issue few months back, some on suggested me to use the code below:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), refValues($params));

function refValues($arr){
    if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0){ //Reference is required for PHP 5.3+
        $refs = array();
        foreach($arr as $key => $value)
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
        return $refs;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Using this again gives the same error. If I invoke the function like this (adding & before $params):

```
$conn->Execute('INSERT INTO some_table (ID, `Index`) VALUES (?,?)', &$params); // 2
```

I get this error:

> Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in ..mypath..\save.php on line

Alternatively, I have tried this definition for function `DbHelper::Execute`:

```
public function Execute($query, $params){
    $this->open();
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query) or die($this->mysqli->error);
    $stmt->{'bind_param'}($params); // 3
    return $stmt->execute() ? $stmt->num_rows : 'ERROR';
}
```

Invoking this shows the error as:

> Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in
>   ..mypath..\dbhelper.php on line

Where as, the parameter count is correct to bind_param, if the function is called properly.

The version of PHP is 5.3.8.

Any help please?

Comment: Why are you making a wrapper around mysqli? If you're ready to advance, check out PDO, which offers a much more OOP API.

Comment: I have tried PDO also, few months back though, but many things just don't work properly. On Googling for errors, it came out that PDO is 'quite' buggy. Otherwise, I do admit that PDO is perhaps the best database access API for PHP.

Comment: 'quite' buggy? I want to know where you heard that. PDO is currently the most evolved and stable of the MySQL (and SQL in general) APIs. Named placeholders and PDOExceptions. That's all I'm sayin'.

Comment: I am not dis-agreeing from your point. As I said, I used PDO some months back, when it, may be, was "NOT STABLE". I have even posted some problems on StackOverflow. You can even Google "pdo bugs". You will find a number of searches in the very first page. Any ways, the bugs might have been fixed by now. I haven't used PDO since then. If it is stable now, I will be more than happy to use it again.

Comment: These bugs were submitted on a wide range dates from 2005 to 2008. All of them were fixed long ago. I don't know what kinds of bugs you've experienced, but I'm using PDO for longer than a few months, and haven't had problems with it since PHP 5.0/5.1.x

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Up votes on your comments mean I was wrong perhaps. But I did have some problems, may be because I was new to PDO and MySQLi then. Leave arguments aside. Back to your original comment "Why are you making a wrapper around mysqli?". I just wanted to free myself from the hassle of creating, opening and closing connections on every page / code file. I am planning to create a persistent connection, for which I will Google and seek help from StackOverflow, if required. If what I am doing is USELESS, tell me then, I won't use it. I am here for seeking help only. Everyone's not perfect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20133/discussion-between-kush-impetus-and-madara-uchiha)

Comment: PDO is indeed very good and should/will become the standard API to all databases in the future. But I disagree that it is the most advanced and/or stable, yet. Plus, it isn't *more* OOP - it's *only* OOP, and that's not necessarily a good thing - don't just blindly follow trends. Both have some advantages, weaknesses and bugs. If we were talking about 'mysql' (no 'i' at the end) - I'd completely agree, but that's not the case. Here's a really nice comparison of the three: http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2012/php-mysql-why-to-upgrade-extmysql/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that has been suggested to you needs to accept `$params` via reference as well. Here's a slightly updated version:

```
function refValues(&$arr)
{
    //Reference is required for PHP 5.3+
    if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0)
    {
        $refs = array();
        foreach(array_keys($arr) as $key)
        {
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
        }
        return $refs;
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: Well Narf! You saved me from scratching my hair off my head. THANKS.