# PHP Session Var Not Transferring Across Pages

Tags: php, html, database

I have a connect file which is included in the header of my files. The header contains a session start, and I have checked that the session ID is the same across pages. I am trying to echo the $_SESSION['userFirstName'] within some HTML to display the users name. I cannot figure out why it it is blank. There are no error messages from Chrome other than the "Notice: Undefined index: userFirstName

Here is my connect.php

```
<?php
/*Login handled here*/
$servername = "localhost";
$usernameDB = "root";
$passwordDB = "";
$nameDB = "teacheasy";

//set user and password to values from form
if ( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) { 
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
} else {
    echo "The values weren't sent";
}

//connect to the database
$_SESSION['connection'] = new mysqli($servername, $usernameDB, $passwordDB,$nameDB);

//Check if the connection was successful
if($_SESSION['connection']->connect_error){
    die("Connection to the database failed: " . $_SESSION['connection']->connect_error);
} else{
//once the DB is connected, get information from the DB to check the records against the data entered
    $sqlUser = "SELECT `teacher_username` FROM `teacher` WHERE `teacher_username`='$user'";
    $sqlPass = "SELECT `password` FROM `teacher` WHERE `password`='$pass'";
    $resultUser = mysqli_query($_SESSION['connection'], $sqlUser);
    $resultPass = mysqli_query($_SESSION['connection'], $sqlPass);
    $textUser = $resultUser->fetch_assoc();
    $textPass = $resultPass->fetch_assoc();

    //get first name and last name to populate the user
    $sqlUserFirstName = "SELECT `first_name` FROM `teacher` WHERE `teacher_username`='$user'";
    $sqlUserLastName = "SELECT `last_name` FROM `teacher` WHERE `teacher_username`='$user'";
    $resultUserFirstName = mysqli_query($_SESSION['connection'], $sqlUserFirstName);
    $resultUserLastName = mysqli_query($_SESSION['connection'], $sqlUserLastName);
    $_SESSION['userFirstName'] = $_POST[$resultUserFirstName->fetch_assoc()];
    $_SESSION['userLastName'] = $_POST[$resultUserLastName->fetch_assoc()];

    //check if the user and password match records in the database
    if($user == $textUser['teacher_username'] && $pass == $textPass['password']){
        //open the calendar if they match
        echo "<script> window.location.assign('../calendar.php'); </script>";
    } else{
        //set this up to load a log in failed page rather than a blank page with error message
        echo "The data entered has no match.";
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any [session_start](http://php.net/session_start) in there.

Comment: That's because it's in the header which is used before this connect

Comment: I don't see any reference to a header either. As an aside, putting a DB connection into the session seems like a bad idea. Another aside, why not use `header` redirects than JS ones?

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot use an array as an array key: `$_SESSION['userFirstName'] = $_POST[$resultUserFirstName->fetch_assoc()];`. What `$_POST` variable do you expect to get using this?

Comment: Be sure to call a session_start on every page to (re)start the session.

Comment: Following from @jeroen's point, why are you doing 2 queries instead of one? And please try and use prepared statements.

Comment: I do start the session and it has been verified via session ID on all pages

Comment: I am doing separate queries in order to only obtain a single value rather than 2 results.

Comment: And both plain-text passwords and selecting users by their password sounds really really really wrong.

Comment: this is for learning not production, so plain text for a password is okay for now

Comment: The users are being selected by their usernames

Comment: Without trying to be harsh, this code is all over the place and to be honest, it may well be worth rewriting from scratch. A few tutorials may well also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you done

```
$user = $_POST['username']
// "SELECT `first_name` FROM `teacher` WHERE `teacher_username`='$user'" // SQL injection here
$_SESSION['userFirstName'] = $_POST[$resultUserFirstName->fetch_assoc()];
```

As @jeroen said in comments `$_SESSION['userFirstName']` must be empty because there is no key in the $_POST that is equals `$resultUserFirstName->fetch_assoc()` which returns an array! . You should be getting an undefined index error.

`$_POST` is an array that holds the variables that have been posted with the http request to your server. It has nothing to do with the data returned from your database query unless `$_POST['username']` === `teacher.first_name` and `teacher.first_name` === `teacher.teacher_username`

try

```
$_SESSION['userFirstName'] = $resultUserFirstName->fetch_assoc()['first_name'];
```

instead of

```
$_SESSION['userFirstName'] = $_POST[$resultUserFirstName->fetch_assoc()];
```

Also you are vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) attacks, and you should make it a happit to **always** use prepared statements. Check this answer on how to [switch to prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45034865/5407848)  if you are used to concatenating.

Comment: Thanks! I still don't have the desired output, I still have a "Notice: Undefined index: userFirstName" error

Comment: This fixed the issue once i added a session start in the connect!